# i don't really understand git extension behavior

Tags: git, git-extensions, gitk

I have few questions about git extension because i use it for 2 month now but i actually do things without really understanding what is going on behind. I'll give you my 3 main points that would certainly help me to understand but don't hesitate to ask for informations if it is unclear.

- How i am supposed to understand how `git extension` shows branches ? indeed, as it is shown in the commit panel, i cannot easily tell about branches as `gitk` allows.
- Why if i do `gitk` on a branche, it does not give the same tree view from another branch ? i thaught that `gitk` was simply giving the "global" tree view, so what does it show ?
- why i have some **local** branches that shows up with `git branch` command line, are also shown in git extension left most panel but are not shown in git extension center panel (i.e commit panel). Actually i have 5 branch: master and 4 branches as feature/branch1, ..., feature/branch4.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted a screenshot, so it is very hard to make out what you're seeing or not seeing.

Here's a screenshot from Git Extensions explaining local and remote branches:

[image]

Also questions like this are better asked in our [gitter channel](https://gitter.im/gitextensions/gitextensions?utm_source=badge&utm_medium=badge&utm_campaign=pr-badge&utm_content=badge).

Comment: sorry, i didn' want to add one as this is not my personal project. I did researches and i am starting to understand it. But that is really the graphical representation at the center  that mostly bugs me. Actually, why there is some times real branches that are shown and some times just a straight line with all commits ? i can't figure out a logic. Thanks for the link, i'll definitly go to see what gitter is.

Comment: Without screenshots of what you're finding confusing it is very difficult to give you a correct advice.
Generally all git UI tools have the same traits.